# Javascript splice for filtering image gallery

Tags: javascript

I am filtering an isotope gallery. Clicking on a button adds to an array called filter. That is working properly, but when the user clicks on an active button, I want the filtered category to be removed from the array. For some reason it isn't.

This is the particular code:

```
if($(this).hasClass('is-checked') && $(this).not('.all')){
  console.log(filterValue);
  filterGroup.splice($.inArray(filterValue, 1));
  console.log(filterGroup);
  $(this).removeClass('is-checked');
}else if ($(this).hasClass('all')) {
  $(this).toggleClass('is-checked');
}else{
  filters[group].push($(this).attr('data-filter'));
  $(this).addClass('is-checked');
}
```

You can see the gallery here http://iris.aimto.be/gallery/gallery.html

If you click 'Thursday' then 'Friday', then click on 'Friday' again you can see the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace by this code

```
if ($(this).hasClass('is-checked') && $(this).not('.all')){
      console.log(filterValue);
      filterGroup.splice(filterGroup.indexOf(filterValue), 1);
      console.log(filterGroup);
      $(this).removeClass('is-checked');
    }else if ($(this).hasClass('all')) {
      $(this).toggleClass('is-checked');
    }else{
      filters[group].push($(this).attr('data-filter'));
      $(this).addClass('is-checked');
    }
```

The [splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/splice) needs the index as first argument

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much!!